# Cannot use a pool after calling end on the pool TypeORM queryBuilder

Tags: query-builder, typeorm

I am trying out some stuff with the TypeORM querybuilder. However after running the code shown below I keep getting the error

`(node:25699) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Cannot use a pool after calling end on the pool`

If it matters if I add the `user` relation first or the `location` relation, because the one that goes first gets added as a relation as expected. The one after that keeps throwing the error.

```
userIds.forEach(async (userId, i) => {
  await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Pin, "user")
    .of(pinIds[i])
    .set(userId);

  await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Pin, "location")
    .of(pinIds[i])
    .set(locationIds[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing creating a connection only once and making the relations with that connection.

```
const connection = await getConnection();
userIds.forEach(async (userId, i) => {
  connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Pin, "user")
    .of(pinIds[i])
    .set(userId);

  connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .relation(Pin, "location")
    .of(pinIds[i])
    .set(locationIds[i]);
});
```